# how to install numpy for python3

Tags: software-installation, python3, numpy

I need help with installing numpy to Ubuntu 16.04. 
after:

```
$ pip3 install numpy
come up always:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy'
```

What to do? How can i install numpy?

Comment: What's wrong with `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy`?

Comment: `sudo pip3 install numpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, when you install any software using *pip*, it defaults to the path: "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy" for installing that software.

Only the **root** user has access to this area of control (better security) and so, you'll need to the keyword `sudo` before such commands to enable that software (in this case, pip) to perform it's operations with a **root** user access level.

So, your command will now become:

```
sudo pip3 install numpy
```

Comment: It worked well... i am a beginner and going trough python course... trying to follow what is there. learning every day something new 
Thank you.

Comment: Why not `pip3 install --user numpy`?

Comment: @Tukadas if this answer helped you solve the problem, then choose it as the best answer for other users in the future  :)

Answer (score 8):

From the terminal run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

This package contains Numpy for Python 3.

For scipy:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
```

For for plotting graphs use  pylab:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

Comment: similarly, I could have installed Pandas: `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas` and followed by I verified as `python3 -c "import numpy, pandas, matplotlib, scipy"` it worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have also installed numpy library easily using [install pip on ubuntu](https://linux4one.com/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18-04-linux4one/). you should enter the following command:

sudo pip3 install numpy